# Android studio, subclass of AppCompatButton does not act like a button

Tags: java, android, button, android-appcompat

I am working on an android app in java, and ive created a sub-class of android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton, because youre not supposed to directly subclass Button. When i create the subclass object (hencforth refered to as "subButton") and add it to the activity via XML, the item looks and acts like a button, however when i do so via Java (programatically) , it looks and acts like a textView instead.

my XML is

```
  <com.example.appName.subButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="xmlTestItem"/>
```

While my Java is

```
 subButton testItem = new subButton(getApplicationContext());
    testItem.setText("javaTestItem");
    testItem.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT ,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    mainListScroll.addView(testItem);
```

but it still only displays text instead of a button. Any clues?

Comment: What happens if you change `getApplicationContext()` to `this`?

Comment: It fixes the issue and makes the button act like a regular button. Thanks! if you wanna  submit this as an answer in statement form instead of question form, ill mark you as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is most likely caused by the use of the application context rather than activity context when instantiating the `subButton` instance. In particular, the themes associated with these contexts, which are used when instantiating view components, are usually different.

As a general rule you should use the context directly available to you at the time. In an activity, this means making use of its own context via `this`.

For more details, see this classic post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7298955/2259854